# Find path to the executing Raku script

Tags: raku

Could someone tell me how I can find, within the executing Raku script itself, the path to the script?

I am looking for the equivalent of this Perl code in Raku:

```
$path=abs_path($0);
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `$*PROGRAM`

see: https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#$*PROGRAM

> $*PROGRAM
>
> Contains the location (in the form of an IO::Path object) of the Raku program being executed.